# Passing standard JavaScript event with composed=false through Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom, lit-element, lit

I have a custom lit web component that contains an `<input>` element inside its Shadow DOM. I want to react to the `change` event fired by the input outside the custom element, but the `change` event has by default `composed: false`, so the event doesn't pass through the Shadow DOM boundary. I could catch the event inside my component implementation, but the `composed` property is read-only, so I can't update it and dispatch the same event object. I could create a new object with  `new Event('change', {'composed': true})`, but then it doesn't have the properties like `target` of the original event. What's a good approach? Should I manually copy the original event's properties to the new event object?

Comment: but target will be probably the input that is inside the shadow DOM, and it shouldn't be "known" from the outside...   Are you sure that you want it this way ?   I think that target should be the component and not the input.

Comment: That's a good start, at least. Should I be firing a 'change' event at all, or some `CustomEvent` instead? I'm wondering if that makes sense from the API point of view - will the user of the component be expecting a 'change' event?

Comment: To choose between a customevent or a change event is just opinable, and probably both are ok. I would go for a change event, if you fire it when a change has happened. (does the data that you are sending fit in a *change* event?). But sending in target something that is inside your component, hidden to the user of the component, is out of question. (for me at least)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to dispatch a single `Event` instance more than once, so even if you could modify the `composed` property of the original event you couldn't redispatch it anyway.

So you need to create a new event to dispatch from your custom element, but the details of how exactly you want to create the event and what it should contain will probably depend on your use case. I'd suggest to try to keep it as simple as possible and make an event that includes the information you need and then dispatch it.

There's probably a reason why the native [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event is not `composed`, but you can simulate propagating it out of your custom element by creating an event with the name `change` and dispatching it from your custom element. You probably don't even need to use [composed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composed) in most cases as just dispatching it from your custom element (`this`) makes it available in the parent scope (one level up from your shadow root) which is where the event probably should be handled in most cases.

The fact that you have an `<input>` in your shadow root should probably be treated as an implementation detail (at least in some cases) and not exposed outside unnecessarily, but when you do need to expose it directly, you can make it available e.g. as a property on your custom element (which could then be accessed from your custom event) or you can include a reference to it in the event object (e.g. in `detail` property of [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) or a property of a custom event class).

For example [here's](https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/blob/5f50d14bd781ed3bbbcf30fe5a74037d92096530/packages/vaadin-text-field/src/vaadin-text-field-mixin.js#L437-L446) how Vaadin components like `<vaadint-text-field>` propagate the `change` event:

```
const changeEvent = new CustomEvent('change', {
  detail: {
    sourceEvent: e
  },
  bubbles: e.bubbles,
  cancelable: e.cancelable
});
this.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
```

Here the original event is explicitly exposed as `event.detail.sourceEvent` so you could for example get the input value from your custom `change` event like `event.detail.sourceEvent.target.value`.

If you expose the input element via a property (e.g. `myInput`) you would not need to use `CustomEvent` and `detail` as then you could do something like `event.target.myInput.value`, or if the original `change` event actually causes a `value` property on your custom element to change, you could just read that instead.

```
// Dispatch event (in your custom element)
const changeEvent = new Event('change', {
  bubbles: e.bubbles,
  cancelable: e.cancelable
});
this.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);

// Read the input value in event handler (assuming your custom element
// has declared `myInput` as a reference to the `<input>`)
event.target.myInput.value
// Alternatively access via shadowRoot (not very nice)
event.target.shadowRoot.querySelector('input').value
```

You could also include custom properties or methods in your event if you create a custom event class like this:

```
// Declare event class once somewhere
class MyChangeEvent extends Event {
  constructor(sourceEvent) {
    super('change', {
      bubbles: sourceEvent.bubbles,
      cancelable: sourceEvent.cancelable,
    });
    this.sourceEvent = sourceEvent;
  }
}

// Trigger a custom event
this.dispatchEvent(new MyChangeEvent(e));

// Access custom event property in an event handler
event.sourceEvent
```

Instead of using the event name `change` you could of course use your own custom event name like `my-change-event` but it should be ok to use `change` when you want your custom element to behave like a native `<input>` which might allow your component to be used as a drop in replacement for a native `<input>` in some situations (with limitations probably) or if you just want to mimic the native `change` event which is already familiar to developers. In most cases it probably doesn't matter if the `change` event you dispatch is created as an `Event`, `CustomEvent` or other instance extending from `Event`.