# Sandbox events inside closed shadow root

Tags: javascript, dom-events, sandbox, shadow-dom

I have a closed shadow root in my document that represents custom controls containing sensitive information, however it seems as though (despite being closed) events will still bubble out of the shadow root into the enclosing DOM, although with the shadow root path removed once exited.

This still allows information to leak into the owning document from closed shadow DOM, enough to say that it encourages keylogging of DOM intended to be sandboxed.

There exists a property on `Event` objects called [`Event.composed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composed) which states:

> The read-only `composed` property of the Event interface returns a boolean value which indicates whether or not the event will propagate across the shadow DOM boundary into the standard DOM.

...which is precisely what I need - however read-only, so not much help in this regard.

Things I've attempted:

- Deleting `Event.prototype.composed` and replacing it with a `false` getter.
- A handler on the owner element of the shadow root and killing any events there, but no matter what I try it seems either `document.addEventListener("keydown", e => console.log(e), true);` will pick up an escapee, or I kill the event early enough that nothing else gets it.

Things I could try:

- Hijacking the `EventTarget.addEventListener` method and wrapping every callback in some sandboxing code to reject events attempting to escape shadow roots... though I can't trust that to work everywhere
- Hijack every event and re-emit it with the `composed` flag `false` - or as a custom event as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67882470/1481699)... though that would result in a performance-sink on mouse or gyro events.
- An iframe instead of a shadow root... but I really cannot trust that to work either with the document being its owner still.

Is there any reliable *and* performant method in Javascript to prevent events from escaping closed shadow roots? Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`mode:"closed"` has nothing to do with Events.

##### **`mode:"closed"`** MDN documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/mode

> When the mode of a shadow root is "closed",
> the shadow root's implementation **internals are inaccessible and unchangeable from JavaScript** in the same way the implementation internals of, for example, the  element are inaccessible and unchangeable from JavaScript.

##### **`composed`** MDN documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composed

> The read-only `composed` property of the Event interface returns a boolean value which indicates whether or not the event will propagate across the shadow DOM boundary into the standard DOM.

This means the `composed` property is read-only **IN** the Event.

You can **not** set it for default Events. **All default Events *escape* shadowDOM**.

You can set `composed` on Custom Events to make **your** Events *escape* shadowDOM:

```
new CustomEvent("myownevent", {
  composed: true,
  bubbles:  true
});
```

##### stop (default) Events *escaping* shadowDOM

You are not saying *how* you tried to *kill* the events.

`evt.stopPropagation()` does the job; but you have to catch them all.

```html
<script>
  const element = (tag,props={}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
  const log = (...args) => document.body.append(...args, element("br"));
  const listen = (scope, type, label) =>
          scope.addEventListener(type, () => log(type, " received on window"));
  listen(window, "click");
  listen(window, "keydown");
  listen(window, "keyup"); // not stopped!
  customElements.define("my-component", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode:"closed"})
             .append(
                element("input", {
                  type:        "text",
                  placeholder: "type something",
                  onkeydown: (evt) => log(evt.type, " in input"),
                  onkeyup:   (evt) => log(evt.type, " in input")
                }),
                element("button", {
                  innerText: "click me",
                  onclick:   (evt) => log("clicked button")
                })
              )
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      const stopPropagation = (type) => this[type] = (evt) => {
        log("stopPropagation ", evt.type);
        evt.stopPropagation();
      }
      stopPropagation("onclick");
      stopPropagation("onkeydown");
    }
  });
</script>
<my-component></my-component>
<hr>
```

Note: `this[type]` does `this["onclick"]` thus `this.onclick` to set an ***inline* event**, no need to use `addEventListener` here unless you want a programmer *using your component* being able to set a click handler on `<my-component>`

Note (and nitpicking): Carefully using my own variable name `evt` instead of `event`, because for historical IE reasons (going back  to the mid 90s) `event` still is a Global `window.event` in all modern browsers.
You *can* use `event`, just understand you are not *using/passing* a **parameter** but using `window.event`

Comment: Unfortunately it looks as though `document.addEventListener("keydown", e => console.log(e), true);` will still capture these events just fine as it takes priority (at least on Firefox) over even the inline event handlers, and to stop propagation at the same level of priority (setting that last flag on `addEventListener` to true) means nothing else gets it.

Comment: Yes, that reverses the order. Note; in a browser context the user can do a whole lot more with F12 Developer tools. ``mode:"closed"`` doesn't do very much. That is why you see ``closed`` hardly being used, there is hardly an advantage.